# Create a seperate HTTPS site on lighttpd?

Tags: https, raspbian, lighttpd

I'm running lighttpd on a Raspbian Pi3 Model B that serves as the HTTP webserver for Pi-Hole, a DNS based adblocker, running on port 80.

I'd like to also have lighttpd listen on port 443 for HTTPS requests, but have it direct to a completely different HTML file instead of Pi-Hole.

How can I do this (using a self-signed SSL certificate)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with mod_proxy.

Add mod_proxy too your list of included modules in lighttpd.conf i.e:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_proxy"
)
```

Then you can redirect requires to 443 (https) somewhere else.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
    proxy.server = (
            "" => ((
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => "8080"
            ))
    )
}
```